I am using ng-zorro range-picker i want set the start date and end date with custom validation
I am using ng-zorro  range-picker i want set the start date in such a way that all dates from tomorrow are disabled and for end date i want all the dates  from yesterday to be disabled how can i achive this
html
<nz-form-item>
  <nz-form-control>
    <nz-range-picker nzFormat="d MMMM Y " [nzAllowClear]="false"
                     formControlName="date" (ngModelChange)="checkValidation()"
                     [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate">
    </nz-range-picker>
  </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>

ts
this.disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean =>
  differenceInCalendarDays(current, this.today) < 0;

i tried this but only the previous date diabled
